# Get the value of an obj attribute knowing its name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of constants,variable in which i keep names.

```
ATTR_ITEM_NAME = 'pro'
```

I check if the attribute is attached to an objects:

```
 if hasattr(obj1, ATTR_ITEM_NAME):
```

then if exist I want the attribute value to be passed to an attribute of an object, something like this:

```
obj2.fm = obj1.ATTR_ITEM_NAME
```

ATTR_ITEM_NAME being a string and not an attribute is an error, I need something that works;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python also has [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) which works like [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#hasattr) but returns the value:

```
obj2.fm = getattr(obj1, ATTR_ITEM_NAME)
```

If you are not sure the attribute exists you could:

- assign a default value (e.g. `None`)

  ```
  DEFAULT = None
  obj2.fm = getattr(obj1, ATTR_ITEM_NAME, DEFAULT)
  ```
- or catch the exception using

  ```
  try:
      obj2.fm = getattr(obj1, ATTR_ITEM_NAME)
  except AttributeError:
      pass  # or do something else...
  ```